# Gnome invites to upgrade to 3.34 even though I'm already on 3.34 [Ubuntu 19.10]

Tags: gnome, updates

I'm on Ubuntu 19.10. Every reboot I get this friendly reminder that I can update Gnome to 3.34, even though I'm already on it!

But I like updates. So when I click on it, it just sits there...

[image: Application Updates screenshot]

... and sits there, and sits there. It does nothing.

Just to make sure, I double-checked which Gnome version I'm currently on:

```
$ cat /usr/share/gnome/gnome-version.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gnome-version>
 <platform>3</platform>
 <minor>34</minor>
 <micro>2</micro>
 <distributor>Ubuntu</distributor>
 <!--<date></date>-->
</gnome-version>
```

So that seems to be good. Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: I think it may be the snap package for the GNOME 3.34 runtime. The "94.6 TB" is also strange.

Comment: Hmmm, how do I check to see if Gnome was installed by Snap? If I recall, it was installed with the Ubuntu upgrade from 18.04 to 19.10.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem. Under 18.04 I installed a free book reader that used Freedesktop.org which then apparently installed a Flathub version of Gnome libraries in order for it to function. I am guessing that when I upgraded to 19.10, that software did not "stay with the group" as it were, and began to confuse the system.

I discovered it in the list of "Add-Ons" in "Ubuntu Software" (snapcraft), tried removing it, and it popped up with a notification that it was needed by "com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate". I uninstalled the book reader (which I never used), and then I was able to successfully remove the Gnome libraries.

Incidentally, this gave me a chance to clean up other add-ons that were apparently also piling up over time and were no longer needed.

The "Update Gnome" notifications now no longer appear, so everything appears kosher. :)